# Document or shred [manual]?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[manual](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/manual) is an undefined tag that originally had 20-some motley questions.  I cleaned up the ones where the tag was just decoration, or should have been a more accurate existing tag, like [command-line] for manually doing something using a command line, or [documentation].

We're left with five questions, all asking to find a user manual or service manual.  I believe all of these are off-topic and should be closed.  Since the tag is ambiguous, it should disappear.  The question is the route:

- Retag the remaining questions with [documentation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/documentation), and deal separately with the disposition of the questions.
- Delete the five questions and the tag will go with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of those questions are not really of use to anyone else, most of the answers points at easy to find resources.

I've deleted them.